# Windows 10: Change active workspace

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10

Is there a function in .net to change the current or active workspace in Windows 10?

Reason: I wanna introduce new hotkeys for changing them alongside `Ctrl+WinKey+ArrowKeys`.

### Edit:

As `Nguyen Kien` Suggested, I can use SendKeys. A problem with this solution could be:

I want to be able to choose workspaces, i.e if I'm in workspace #1, I wanna hit WinKey+5 to jump to workspace 5. So I would need to send keys four times. Then again I would have to keep track of the current workspace which I could loose track of( changing workspace using mouse ).

Comment: You can use SendKeys to send combine: Ctrl+WinKey+ArrowKeys

Comment: @NguyenKien That sounds to be a very interesting solution. I'll definitely try it. thanks.